# how to consume a rest api method GET with parametres in angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot

i'm new to angular and spring boot , i'm working on a simple project that creates a rest controller and i'm supposed to consume it in an angular project.

this is my rest controller:

```js
 @RestController
 public class CalculatriceController {

 @Autowired
 private CalculatriceService calculatriceservice;

 @GetMapping("/add/{a}/{b}")
 public Integer ajouter(@PathVariable int a, @PathVariable int b) {
     return calculatriceservice.add(a, b);
 }

 @GetMapping("/soustraire/{a}/{b}")
 public Integer soustraire(@PathVariable int a, @PathVariable int b) {
     return calculatriceservice.soustraire(a, b);
 }

 @GetMapping("/multiplier/{a}/{b}")
 public Integer multiplier(@PathVariable int a, @PathVariable int b) {
     return calculatriceservice.multiplier(a, b);
 }

 @GetMapping("/diviser/{a}/{b}")
 public ResponseEntity diviser(@PathVariable int a, @PathVariable int b) {
     if (b != 0) {
         return new ResponseEntity((float) calculatriceservice.divide(a, b), HttpStatus.OK);
     } else {
         return new ResponseEntity<>("cannot divide by 0", HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
     }
 }}
```

the service i created is this :

```js
    @Service
    public class CalculatriceService {
    public int add(int a,int b) {
        return a+b;
    }
    public int soustraire(int a,int b) {
        return a-b;
    }
    public int multiplier(int a,int b) {
        return a*b;
    }
    public float divide(int a,int b) {
        System.out.println("la valeur de a sur b est "+(float)a/b);
        return (float) a/b;
    }}
```

I'm trying to create a service in angular 8 in which i call these functions , I injected the httpClient service  into the constructor of the service but I didn't know how to call these functions so please any help? Thank you

Comment: Please share your angular code, what you have tried ?

Comment: Please go through the Angular Spring CRUD tutorial - https://www.javainuse.com/spring/ang7-crud

Comment: hello this is my angular code :                                                                                            import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
  


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CalculService {

  constructor(
    private httpClient:HttpClient
  ) { 
    }
x:number; y:number
     add()
  {
    return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:8080/add+"/"+this.x+"/"+this.y');
  }